# Resource Picker not liking my array - React shopify app-bridge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shopify-api, shopify-app-bridge

So, i'm getting the selected items from the resource picker and trying to use it for `initialSelectionIds`.

However i'm getting this error when using it as in the beginning it is empty: I'm also not sure how to get `selectedValue` into the correct format.
error:

`` appBridgeError: APP::ERROR::INVALID_OPTIONS: `type_error_expected_object` thrown for path: ['initialSelectionIds']['0'] and value: `[] ``

```
const handleSelection = (resources) => {
      const idsFromResources = resources.selection.map(v => "id:'" + v.id +'\'');
      const namesFromResources = resources.selection.map(p => p.title);

      selectedValue = JSON.parse(idsFromResources); <Page
    title='Allergen Selector'
    primaryAction={{
      content: 'Select Allergens',
      onAction: () => opend(),
      
    }}>
      <ResourcePicker
        resourceType="Product"
        showVariants={true}
        open={active}
        onSelection={(resources) => handleSelection(resources)}
        onCancel={handleToggle}


      initialSelectionIds={[selectedValue ]   }
     />
  </Page>
```

But it works when i use this:

```
const productWithAllVariantsSelected = {
    id: 'gid://shopify/Product/6337793261759',
  };
<ResourcePicker
            resourceType="Product"
            showVariants={true}
            open={active}
            onSelection={(resources) => handleSelection(resources)}
            onCancel={handleToggle}
            initialSelectionIds={[productWithAllVariantsSelected] }
         />
```